# Setting JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, environment-variables

How do I set `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm` ...E ? The instructions say to use

```
INSTALL4J JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

but I get an error that says:

```
INSTALL4J: command not found
```

I have downloaded INSTALL4J and I installed it (I think). It asked all sorts of questions that I did not know how to answer, so I just hit "Next" a lot. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Comment: Where are you getting your instructions from?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you get the instructions, but there's another way to set the `JAVA_HOME` as follows:

**For single user:**

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

you can change the `vi` to your favorite text editor like `gedit`

then at the end of the file put this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path-to-java>
```

where `<path-to-java>` in your case might be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java`

now set `PATH` as follows (below `JAVA_HOME`):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin
```

now save the file and exit, log out and login to see the new changes.

**Note:** if you want to set `JAVA_HOME` for **all users** this link might help you:
[source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/)