# Set different java version for different programs

Tags: java, versions

I use some programs that have known bugs when using Java 1.7.x (default on my computer), issues that would be fixed using Java 1.6. However I also use program that works fine with the default Java and have known issues with older versions.

How can I run the program `myprogram` specifing the version of Java to use?

Answer (score 1):

There is a shell environment variable, `JAVA_HOME` that can be set to use a java version from a specific directory. It needs to be exported, and should contain the path of the `bin` subdirectory of the java version. Also, the same directory should be first (or before `/usr/bin`) in `PATH`.

The variable can be set in a script used to start an individual program.

You could find the bin directories of installed versions using something like

```
$ locate -b '\appletviewer'
```

For details on setting the variable, see [Setting JAVA_HOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421954/setting-java-home).

There is a similar variable `JDK_HOME` for the JDK.

Comment: I tried to set these, but the software seems to use the system version...

Comment: I just did this: created a bash script and before calling the program I set:

export JAVA_HOME='pathtojavaversionbin'

Comment: Can you show your exact command, and the output of `echo $PATH`? Append it to the question as additional details - in a comment, it is not very readable.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` doesn't strictly need to be exported. `JAVA_HOME='pathtojavaversionbin' /path/to/command` works fine