# How to run an application on a specific Java version?

Tags: java, 17.10, openjdk

How can I run an application with a specific Java version? I have three Java versions intstalled:

```
myuser@mysystem:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
* 1            /opt/jdk-9.0.4/bin/java                          1         manual mode
  2            /opt/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java                       1         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

I have Java 9 set as default and I'd like to keep it that way. Still, an application named `pdfsam` doesn't seem to work properly with Java 9. What command is necessary to run it with openjdk (option 3)?

Comment: Normally, right after the choices are displayed, the message below is also displayed Press <enter> to keep the current choice [*], or type selection number: as you can see, it explains that the line marked by a star (*) and the choice activated by default, and if you want to change it, you just have to enter the number of the selection and click on `<enter>`

Comment: That's exactly what I described not to want, as I wanna keep Java 9 as default. The reason is that most of my applications run well on Java 9, except pdfsam, that runs best on OpenJDK 8 and NetBeans that also only runs on Java 8. I though best would be a parameter at execution time to tell what Java version to pick. But couldn't find such an option. I have the feeling there is no such option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set different java version for different programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556474/set-different-java-version-for-different-programs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default Java version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version)